# How do you set the proxy IP with Phproxy?

Tags: php, proxy

I just downloaded PhProxy from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/poxy/). When I went to some IP locator site my IP was a Dallas/Texas IP. Is there any way to change the IP PhProxy uses? I couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: Wait a sec. I think Phproxy is using the IP of my server, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHProxy - like all proxies - accepts requests from any of a number of IPs and acts on their behalf to fulfill that request. The IP you're seeing is almost certainly the IP address of your webserver, and no you can't edit some setting to change it. Your server makes a request to some address and includes its own address - this is how the remote end knows how to answer back. You couldn't change this with a PHProxy setting even if you wanted to - if you could, your packets wouldn't get back to you.

You could get a different webhost, if a Dallas-located IP is a real problem, but it would be locked to the new webhost just the same. Webservers can't exactly IP-hop...